# Missing Material Eyedropper

Tags: 3d-view

[image]

I've got custom floating window to manage with materials (work in progress), so I don't need to really open materials property tab.
Everything functions good, faster workflow! Except I can't hook the eye dropper, why is that?

**What it should look like:**

[image]